# change string in c with only pointer

Tags: c, algorithm

There is pointer to string let say:  char *p = "abcdef"
I want to delete some of the chars.

Let say every second char, so i want to get *p="ace"
my algorithm is something like:

```
int i=1,j=1

for(;p != '\0';p++,i++)
    if (i % 2 ==0) 
        *(p - j++)= *p
*(p-j)='\0'
```

This algorithm is find the every second char of course but not matter how I try to write the "delete" process or there are compilation errors or the string is unchanged.

I start to believe there is no way to solve that issue without any malloc help.
Again i need to do it on O(n) without any other STRINGS arrays.

Comment: I think it would be better to copy chars from one string to another based on whether it is in an even position or not.

Comment: "i need to do it on O(n) without any other STRINGS arrays."  Why is there this limitation?

Comment: There are some characters (hex 0x3b) missing from your source.

Comment: You should compare `*p` (the char), not `p` (the pointer), with `'\0'`.

Comment: What the Op means is that the work should be done in-place.

Comment: @chux    i got similar question on phone interview several weeks ago. It is not matter now cause i should answer it in less then 1 hour. The question sounds easy to be done, but nobody has show me something work. Again the task is you get a pointer  to string and you job is to  erase every second latter from it. You can't open any new String and you can read the String only once

Comment: Provbide a [mcve]. Modifying a string literal invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Get a modifiable string.  Find a char that you need to 'delete', and copy every char above it, including the terminating NUL, down one.  Rinse, repeat.

Comment: @user8184628 Tip:  put [limitations and their rational](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637791/change-string-in-c-with-only-pointer/44638102?noredirect=1#comment76262013_44637791) in the post.

Comment: Since the new string will be definitely shorter than the original one, start reading at stride 2 and write at stride 1. Finish with `\0`. Should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

- `p != '\0'` should be `*p != '\0'`(or `*p != 0` or `*p`).
- `i` should be initialized to `0`. (You are keeping the wrong ones.)
- `j` should be initialized to `0`. (Off by one error.)
- `j` needs to be incremented each time `p` is incremented.

Your code would be more readable and less fragile if you avoided offsets relative to an unrelated pointer.

```
void filter_inplace(char* src) {
   char* dst = src;
   for (size_t i=0; src[i]; ++i) {
      if (i % 2 == 0)
         *(dst++) = src[i];
   }

   *dst = 0;
}
```

Alternative:

```
void filter_inplace(char* src) {
   char* dst = src;
   while (1) {
      if (!*src) break;
      *(dst++) = *(src++);
      if (!*src) break;
      src++;
   }

   *dst = 0;
}
```

---

Of course, you can't do the following because `p` points to read-only memory:

```
char* p = "abcdef";  # XXX Should be "const char*".
filter_inplace(p);   # XXX Overwrites read-only memory.
```

You could do the following:

```
char p[] = "abcdef";
filter_inplace(p);
```

You could do the following:

```
char* p = strdup("abcdef");
filter_inplace(p);
free(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I start to believe there is no way to solve that issue without any malloc help. Again i need to do it on O(n) without any other STRINGS arrays.

Kind of true. At least it is true that it can't be done without another string. Even if you used `malloc` (or `strdup`) for getting memory I would still consider it another string.

So as long a you initialize the char pointer like:

```
char *p = "abcdef";
```

it can **not** be done. You can't change any character in the string `"abcdef"`.

If the above code was changed to

```
char p[] = "abcdef";
```

you would be able to do what you a trying. But even this could be considered as using another string as you have both the initializer string and char array.